# Electron app run with --no-sandbox generates warnings and errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to write my first electron app and deploy it to a system that requires me to run with the `--no-sandbox` option (I don't have root/sudo permissions on the system). While I am able to run with the `--no-sandbox` option, I see the following messages when I try to open a dialog to pick a file.

I can run vscode on the same system, and it also needs the `--no-sandbox` option, but I have not seen any of these messages while using vscode,  so I assume it has something to do with the way may app is setup,  or they way I am opening the dialog.

```
Error creating proxy: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:” (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Error creating proxy: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:” (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Error creating proxy: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:” (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Error creating proxy: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:” (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Error creating proxy: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:” (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Gtk-Message: 11:03:02.463: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

(my-first-electron:158778): dconf-WARNING **: 11:03:02.658: failed to commit changes to dconf: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”

(my-first-electron:158778): dconf-WARNING **: 11:03:02.705: failed to commit changes to dconf: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”

(my-first-electron:158778): dconf-WARNING **: 11:03:02.714: failed to commit changes to dconf: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”
```

Here is an example of how I am opening the dialog.

```
import { remote } from 'electron'
```

then later

```
buttonClicked = () => {
    console.log(this)
    ipcRenderer.send('do-something')
    const dialog = remote.dialog
    console.log(dialog.showOpenDialogSync(remote.getCurrentWindow(), {
        properties: ['openFile']
    }))

}
```

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring out a solution or root cause to this?

Comment: No I have not found a solution as of yet.

Comment: Any solution to this yet? Recently started experiencing this with an electron app that I am maintaining

Comment: no,  but I have not tried recently.  The systems I work on have recently been upgraded to REL8 for 7,  so I will give it a shot and see if I still have the same issue,  or if a more recent version of electron solves it.